# Save and Get network printer options

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, printing

My goal is to send a PDF to a printer with specific sheet feeder, that is configured a first time by print option dialog (or just a form with network printer, tray, and margin).

I've seek about `PrintDocument`, `PrintDialog` (from System.Windows.Forms) and `PrinterSettings`

I can show network printer, save the selected network printer and I can use this with `PrinterSettings.PrinterName` but my issue is on tray's choice. I have no option to select this and customer that use my application can take every printer that exists.

So how I can show all the tray of printer selected, save it and use it to print ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersource.aspx

contains useful information?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you, I was looking on different word :)